# Getting null from firebase cloud despite everything is correct

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Cloud Function in TypeScript, which  has `async` calls within.

```
exports.validateOtp = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
  phoneNumber = data.phoneNumber;
  otp = data.otp;
  let email:string = data.email;
  let password:string = data.password;
  let displayName:string= data.displayName;

  authFunction.otpValidation(phoneNumber,otp,(otpErr,otpValue) => {
    if(otpErr){
      console.error(otpErr);
      return {otpErr};
    }else{ 
    return authFunction.createUser(email,false,phoneNumber,password,displayName,false,(err,value) => {
        if(err) 
        {
          console.error(err);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }
        else{
          console.log(value); 
          return Promise.resolve(value);
        }                  
          });
    } 
});
  });
```

Below is the implementation of `authFunction.otpValidation`

```
 otpValidation(phoneNumber:string, otp:string,callback:Function){
  let otpValidationApi:string = "https://<api>/verifyRequestOTP.php?authkey="+this.authKey+"&mobile="+phoneNumber+
  "&otp="+otp;
  https.get(otpValidationApi, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
      });
      resp.on('end', () => {
        let result = JSON.parse(data);
        var y=result.type;
        callback(null,y);
      });
  }).on("error",(err)=>{
    console.log("Error: "+err.message);
  });
 }
```

I'm trying to catch its output/return value over Android app using:

```
private static FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
mFunctions.getHttpsCallable(nameOfFunction).call(data)
           .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
               @Override
               public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                   String result2 = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                   return result2;
               }
           });
```

However the `result2` variable in Android code is always returning null even if the Cloud Function work well as expected.

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: What is `authFunction.otpValidation`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen edited the question adding authFunction.otpValidation method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `otpValidation` is also calling a HTTP API, you need to have it return a promise and then "bubble" the promises up and out of the Cloud Function. Right now you're not returning anything from the top level code, and that means Cloud Functions may shut your code down at any moment after the final `}` is run, which is likely while the HTTP call is still running (let alone the `createUser` call).

The first step is to have `otpValidation` return a promise, and resolve/reject that promise:

```
 otpValidation(phoneNumber:string, otp:string): Promise<Any> {
   let otpValidationApi:string = "https://<api>/verifyRequestOTP.php?authkey="+this.authKey+"&mobile="+phoneNumber+
  "&otp="+otp;
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     https.get(otpValidationApi, (resp) => {
       let data = '';
       resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
         data += chunk;
       });
       resp.on('end', () => {
         let result = JSON.parse(data);
         var y=result.type;
         resolve(y);
       });
     }).on("error",(err)=>{
       console.log("Error: "+err.message);
       reject(err);
     });
   });
 }
```

With that out of the way, you can return the result from calling `otpValidation` and chain all the `then()` calls together:

```
exports.validateOtp = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
  phoneNumber = data.phoneNumber;
  otp = data.otp;
  let email:string = data.email;
  let password:string = data.password;
  let displayName:string= data.displayName;

  return authFunction.otpValidation(phoneNumber,otp).then(function(optValue) {
    return authFunction.createUser(email,false,phoneNumber,password,displayName,false,(err,value) => {
        if(err) 
        {
          console.error(err);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }
        else{
          console.log(value); 
          return Promise.resolve(value);
        }                  
      });
    } 
});
```

From reading the rest of the code, you might have to convert `authFunction.createUser` to return a promise too. If so, the approach will be the same as what I've done for your `auth.otpValidation` above.

Comment: This worked well..Thanks for the help Frank...I must say, firebase dev team is working really hard to support its users :)

Comment: We like helping fellow developers. That you're using Firebase is just a bonus. ;-)